# Intellisense missing for one project in C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, silverlight-5.0

It used to work, then one day after a compile intellisense disappeared. It would show all associated system methods and variables when I hit Ctrl + Space, but nothing that I wrote. Even under the Object Browser, the container for the project has zero namespaces underneath it. All the appropriate check boxes are checked in the options as well. Deleted the SUO files too. Unloading and reloading project doesnt work.

Out of ideas. Thoughts?

One thing to note, I did uninstall Resharper after the trial ended. But I want to assume that would break every project, not just one. Also, the project that broke is the only Silverlight project in the solution.

Comment: Are you sharing code as linked files with different projects? That is, do you have _another_ project with the same source code files but a different build target (Xamarin.Android, WPF, etc?)

Comment: Nope. The solution has remain untouched for the most part. Weird thing is that it works for other developers on the team, just not me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Tools/ Imports and Exports Settings / and choose Reset all settings.

Comment: Did that multiple times and nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C# (or All Languages)->General
```

and enable `Auto List Members` and `Parameter Information` in right hand side pane.